# How do I develop nodeJS microservices using docker & VS Code?

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, microservices, development-environment

I'm experimenting with docker micro-services and I'm refactoring an existing NodeJS app to run as several separate entities. What I'm used to doing is running it locally (using `npm start`) and whenever I save my changes, it redeploys everything locally instantly.

How do I set up **VSCode** with it's docker extension to work in this way? I've let **VSCode** create the **Dockerfile** \ **docker-compose.yml** files for each micro-service.

The guides I'm finding around the place imply pushing each change to an image repo, which when you're making small changes, seems long winded

EDIT - Okay. I got it building and deploying manually. I've had to run the build command in CMD instead of GIT Bash (minor frustration... but nothing I can't live with). Is there a way to automate this instead? So whenever a change happens inside of the directory, it just starts the build process again.

Comment: You would only need to push to an image repo if you want to run your images on a different machine from the one that built the images. For your local development, you can just run the images that are on your computer. Once you have finished developing and want to test it in the wild, then you can push the images to a remote repo and have your application use those images.